# Harry potter philosopher's stone chapter 3

Tags: grammar

'He hoped the roof wasn't going to fall in, although he might be warmer if it did '

How is it possible to be warm when roof falls?

Comment: Could be an ironic way of saying that the interior of the building was so cold that the absence of a roof would only make it warmer. It wouldn't really, that would just be a figurative way of saying it was unbearably cold.

Comment: For those of us who don't have a copy to hand, what is the context? Where is 'he'?

Comment: If the roof caved in he'd probably be killed - and as a heathen warlock / male witch, Harry Potter might thus end up in Hell, which by all accounts is pretty warm!

Answer (score 1):

They were staying in a hut in the middle of a storm.

> As night fell, the promised storm blew up around them. **Spray from the high waves splattered the walls of the hut and a fierce wind rattled the filthy windows.**

> The storm raged more and more ferociously as the night went on. Harry couldn’t sleep. He **shivered** ...

Harry was on the floor curled up "under
the thinnest, most ragged blanket".

It's an ironic way to put it. If the roof had fallen in, it might have served as a more comfortable and warmer blanket than the thin worn-out cover he got.

Comment: Wouldn't he have qualified for an equally-warm [pine overcoat](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pine_overcoat)?

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says.  The house is so cold inside that it might actually be warmer if there is no roof!

(If I recall, Harry has been taken to a freezing-cold shack on a rocky island somewhere off the coast of Britain)